# Batch reading features from many Geodatabases in R

Tags: r, merge, esri-geodatabase, batch

I would like to learn to batch import from many geodatabases at once and merge the files together into a new unified shapefile. All of the GDBs and Features have a similar name and file structure. For example GDB1, GDB2, GDB3,...ect. and inside each have shp1, shp2, and shp3.....ect.

From other posts in the group I learned that if these features were not withing GDBs I could simply create a list of the files....

```
shp_files <- list.files(wd,  pattern = glob2rx("*.shp")
```

and then use rbind and lapply to merge them together....

```
merged<-do.call(rbind, lapply(shp_files, rgdal::readOGR))
```

But how can I alter this code to work if the files are in a GDB or if the bundle of features are in a zipped folder?

Comment: You've named your **feature classes** "shp1, shp2, shp3..."?  That's mighty confusing.  Shapefiles are a file-based data format.  File geodatabase is a completely different file-based format. You cannot *store* shapefiles in a file geodatabase, only ***convert*** them to FGDB tables.

Comment: Ahh.. thank you! I didn’t know that. I think part of the reason I am not finding code for this online is I am not using the right terminology. Also... yes it’s basically named that way, and I just wanted to use the most simple example.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started with reading in all of your feature classes, then you can perform a similar operation to what you've included in your question.

```
library(sf)
path<-"C:/Users/GIS Data/Some Folder/your.gdb"
gdb<-st_layers(path)
list_of_features<-purrr::map(gdb$name,~st_read(dsn=path,layer=.))
```

`st_layers` will list all of the names within your gdb which we are then passing to `purrr::map` which takes the list of names and for each name will read that into R from your gdb.